# Looking at serial port traffic

Tags: usb-modem, serial-port

I'm a Windoze guy so I'm kinda lost here.

Usually when I want to see what's happening on a serial port IE `com 1`, I fire up PuTTY and point it at `Com 1` and I'm done.

In Linux I don't have PuTTY.

More specifically I have an ARM board talking on a USB cable to `/dev/ttyACM0` and I want to see what it is sending.

I've made a little program in Qt that reads the `/dev/ttyACM0` and it is working to a certain degree but some data I'm getting looks wack so I want to confirm it.

When I plug the ARM board into the Win7 laptop it doesn't know what to do with it so I can't even use PuTTY.

How can I get PuTTY or equivalent application in Ubuntu ?

Comment: Have you tried: sudo apt-get install putty ?
Or some [other program for talking to the serial port](http://www.cyberciti.biz/hardware/5-linux-unix-commands-for-connecting-to-the-serial-console/),
such as "cu" or "screen" ?

Answer (score 2):

Easy game, in linux everything is a file! 
To check the board response use:

```
cat /dev/ttyACM0
```

to write data to serial use echo

```
sudo echo -e "YO" > /dev/ttyACM0
```

Answer (score 0):

Read from serial port:

```
hexdump -v -e '/1 "%02X "' /dev/ttyUSB0
```

To add timeout to the process:

```
timeout 5 hexdump -v -e '/1 "%02X "'
```

I mentioned 5 means 5 seconds.

Write:

```
echo -e "\xFC\x00" > /dev/ttyUSB0
```